# pointer indirection confusion

Tags: c

I have an array as:

```
int x[3][5]={
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {6,7,8,9,10},
        {11,12,13,14,15}
        };
```

1. What does *x refer to?
2. *(*x+2)+5 refer to "8".How does that happen?
3. Is *(*x+2) same as *(*x)+2?
4. What if I do:

   *n=&x;
   Where is the pointer n pointing to? if it would have been only x and not an & then it would have been the base address.What for now?

Comment: Looks a lot like homework. Could you please at least try to answer it yourself first?

Comment: I can easily do that by running the program.I was in need of an explanation dear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `*x` is a dereference operation. In other words, "give me what `x` is pointing at". Since this is an array (of arrays), dereferencing x will give you the first array. This is equivalent to the array access syntax of `x[0]`.
2. `*(*x+2)+5` is equivalent to `x[0][2] + 5`, which gives you 8. This is because:
   `*x` is the same as `x[0]` (see #1) and `*(x + 2)` is the same as `x[2]`. Once you've done two dereferences, you've gone from an array of arrays (similar to a double-pointer) to an array (single pointer) to an actual number (the third item in the first array). Then, it's just 3 + 5 = 8.
3. `*(*x+2)` is equivalent to `x[0][2]` (see #2), which is 3 (third element in array). However, `*(*x) + 2` gives you `x[0][0] + 2` (first element in array plus 2), which is 1 + 2 = 3. Same answer, but very different way of getting it.

Comment: You mean if I have *(*x+1) I would first find where it points to? i.e x[0][0] and then add 1 to the value which it points to?Wont it be the same as *(*x)+1 ?

Comment: @fahad *(*x+1) would be x[0][1], which is the second element in the first array. *(*x)+1 means to take x[0][0] and add 1 to the value. Again, in your particular case, they are both equal to 2.

Answer (score 6):

`*x` refers to the first array ({1,2,3,4,5}), and is equivalent to x[0]. Adding one to `x` move to the next array, so `*(x+1)` would refer to the second array, and would be equivalent to x[1].

`*(*x + 2)` is therefore the third element in the first array, which is 3. This means that `*(*x + 2) + 5` is equal to 8.

The parentheses matter a lot, for example `*(*(x+2))` would be the first element in the third array.

`*(*x + 2)` results in the same value as `*(*x) + 2`, but does not use the same element of the array.

Comment: `*x` is not a pointer, it is an array.  It might decay to a pointer in some cases, but not always.  For example, try `sizeof *x`.

Answer (score 1):

x is a `int**` so it's like if you have a first layer of pointers and everyone of them point to a `int*` (so an array of `int`).

When you write `*x` you obtain the address that contains the address which points to the first row of your multi dimensional array.

So if you take `(*x + 2)` if it's like referencing to first row of you array and then add 2 to the address: you obtain the address of the third element of first row. But since this is still a pointer you add an external `*(*x+2)` to exactly obtain third element of first row.

Comment: `x` is not an `int **`.  `x` can never even decay to `int **`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

```
typedef int Int5[5];
Int5 x[3];
```

`x` is an array with 3 elements.  Each of those three elements is a array of 5 ints.

- What does *x refer to?

`x` is the same as '&x[0]`so`*x`is the same as`x[0]` which is the first 5-element array.

- *(*x+2)+5 refer to "8".   How does that happen?

`*x` is x[0], and `x+2` is `&x[2]` so `*x+2` is `&x[0][2]` and `*(*x + 2)` is `x[0][2]` which happens to be 3.  Add five to that for 8.

- Is *(*x+2) same as *(*x)+2?

`*(*x+2)` is `x[0][2]` as we've seen.  `*(*x)` would be x[0][0], so `*(*x)+2` is `x[0][0]+2`.  So both `*(*x+2)` and `*(*x)+2` end up equaling 3, but that is merely a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are 100% correct and I will just generally explain this part `*n=&x` in general terms

`&x` generates a pointer (variable containing an address of another variable) and stores it in `n` and to get the value pointed to by n, you `*n` called de referencing or indirection.

To really understand this pointer business, you need to study how computers store values in memory.

Comment: `*n = some_value` will assign the value `some_value` to the **memory** the pointer `n` is pointing to. It doesn't "store [the value] in `n`" like you answered. There's a difference between `n = some_value` and `*n = some_value`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but i was really really trying to make this answer fit for even a 5 year old who wants to know what a pointer is.